# Php code for create multiple array json

Tags: php, json

I want to create multiple array of json string using php. Json must be like this

```
[{
    app:[{"id":"3","image_title":"Fashion","image_url":"6968ec4b67315f81bbf3b893ca02a195.jpg"}],
    app2:[{"id":"3","image_title":"Fashion","image_url":"6968ec4b67315f81bbf3b893ca02a195.jpg"},
      {"id":"3","image_title":"Fashion","image_url":"6968ec4b67315f81bbf3b893ca02a195.jpg"},
      {"id":"3","image_title":"Fashion","image_url":"6968ec4b67315f81bbf3b893ca02a195.jpg"}]
}]
```

when i am using

```
$array = array(
array( "ad1"=>
    array("id"=>"3", "image_title"=>"Fashion", "image_url"=> "6968ec4b67315f81bbf3b893ca02a195.jpg")
    ),
    array( "ad2"=>
    array("id"=>"4", "image_title"=>"Fashion", "image_url"=> "6968ec4b67315f81bbf3b893ca02a195.jpg"),
    array("id"=>"5", "image_title"=>"Fashion", "image_url"=> "6968ec4b67315f81bbf3b893ca02a195.jpg"),
    array("id"=>"6", "image_title"=>"Fashion", "image_url"=> "6968ec4b67315f81bbf3b893ca02a195.jpg")
    )
);
echo json_encode($array);
```

I got the result is

```
[{"ad1":{"id":"3","image_title":"Fashion","image_url":"6968ec4b67315f81bbf3b893ca02a195.jpg"}},
{"ad2":{"id":"4","image_title":"Fashion","image_url":"6968ec4b67315f81bbf3b893ca02a195.jpg"},
"0":{"id":"5","image_title":"Fashion","image_url":"6968ec4b67315f81bbf3b893ca02a195.jpg"},
"1":{"id":"6","image_title":"Fashion","image_url":"6968ec4b67315f81bbf3b893ca02a195.jpg"}}]
```

It showing 0 and 1 in id 5 and 6.

How to correct it?
Please help me?

Comment: yes, it's possible. Post your current input data

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please review the guide on [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Remember to add what you have tried already, preferably with code snippets.

Comment: use json_encode function to convert your php array to json array

Comment: Just create an array that follows your desired output structure and perform json_encode. PHP will do the rest.

Comment: I have updated question. pls check it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your array should look something like this:

```
$array = [
    [
        'app' => [
            'id' => 3, 'image_title' => 'Fashion', // and do so on
        ],
        'app2' => [
            ['id' => 3, 'image_title' => 'Fashion',], // and do so on
            ['id' => 3, 'image_title' => 'Fashion',], // and do so on
            ['id' => 3, 'image_title' => 'Fashion',], // and do so on
        ],
    ]
];

echo json_encode($array);
```

And then the output should be something like what you described:

```
[{
    app:[{"id":"3","image_title":"Fashion","image_url":"6968ec4b67315f81bbf3b893ca02a195.jpg"}],
    app2:[{"id":"3","image_title":"Fashion","image_url":"6968ec4b67315f81bbf3b893ca02a195.jpg"},
      {"id":"3","image_title":"Fashion","image_url":"6968ec4b67315f81bbf3b893ca02a195.jpg"},
      {"id":"3","image_title":"Fashion","image_url":"6968ec4b67315f81bbf3b893ca02a195.jpg"}]
}]
```

It may differ a bit, for example, keys get encapsulated in double quotes and integers (that are actually integers, not strings containing numbers) will be without double quotes. Double quotes and other special characters may be escaped (`\"`) in a JSON string.

Hope it helps.

Comment: It shows the result is [{"app":{"id":3,"image_title":"Fashion"},"app2":{"id":3,"image_title":"Fashion"}}]. app2 showing only one array.

Comment: Quite right, I forgot that that too should've been arrays ;)

Comment: Is there any way to do?

Comment: Thank you Raphioly